# Internet Explorer 10 break-inside

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I try to use multi-column in CSS3. I have problem with column break. Is ok with chrome and Firefox, but not with internet explorer 10 & 11. With IE it work with the first column, but not with the other.

http://jsfiddle.net/JYr5G/5/ for view my exemple

I use in css:

```
-webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
-moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
break-inside:avoid;
```

Any idea how to solve that ?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's an option for you, but after I removed `float:left` from the list items, `break-inside:avoid` works as intended in every column.

http://jsfiddle.net/r3TpW/

Answer (score 2):

I think IE 10-11 requires this

```
-webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
-moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
break-inside:avoid-column;
```

the `break-inside:avoid-column;` being the change.

http://jsfiddle.net/JYr5G/8/

Comment: Exactly the same result

Comment: It's from the IE Dev Center
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772193(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes it want I want, but not work. It's work for you ? What ie version you have ?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried -ms- prefix yet?

```
-webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
-moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
-ms-column-break-inside: avoid;
break-inside:avoid;
```

I changed your example: http://jsfiddle.net/JYr5G/9/

Comment: If I remove "break-inside:avoid;", the "-ms-column-break-inside: avoid;" have no effect. It don't work with the first column now.